# Illustrator - Distorted offset path

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, path

I have a problem with some paths when I increment Offset path tool on it. In some cases the offset I create looks like this:

[image]

I can't really find out what's the problem with this path (red line). On some of paths in my document it works fine but for others it looks like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility...

Offset path behaves differently on open paths and open *compound* paths. A regular open path is offset from the path itself, whereas a compound path is treated as if the path was closed (notice the erroneous path connects the two end points of the original path).

Take these two otherwise identical paths for example:

[image]

There shouldn't be any need for a compound path if it's just a single path, so release any compound paths. If you do need compound paths though you may need to release the compound path, offset, then re-create the compound path again.